# Get File Changes by Pull RequestId in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, pull-request

I need to get the file changes in a perticular Pull Request in Azure Devops using ResAPI or DotNet Library.

I don't want file changes from Commits in PR.

I didn't find Rest API, is there any way to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a pull request is to merge the commits from `BranchB` to `BranchA`, we can use the [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/diffs/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP#between-branches) to get git diff **between branches**.

In my case, I created a PR to merge `BranchB` to `BranchA`.

```
            "title": "PR: B->A",
            "sourceRefName": "refs/heads/BranchB",
            "targetRefName": "refs/heads/BranchA",
```

Then I called the sample API and got the response like below.

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{TheRepoName}/diffs/commits?baseVersion=BranchA&targetVersion=BranchB&api-version=7.1-preview.1
```

[image: GIT Diff]

Hope this workaround could be helpful.

Comment: It worked, Thanks Alvin Zhao-MSFT

Comment: @Alvin Zhao if this PR has multiple commits and they all modifies the same file, would this API return multiple changes of single file or single change as a whole compare with target branch ?